# Unable to get form data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Alright, so I've been fidgeting with this for hours with no luck.

I have multiple forms on a page (6 in total) and each form has this kinda structure

**form 1**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="Television_form">
.
.
.
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="Television" name="save"> Save</button
</form>
```

**form 2**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="Video_form">
    .
    .
    .
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="Video" name="save"> Save</button
    </form>
```

I'm now trying to get the *form data* when someone clicks **"save"** .
Here's the jquery code for it :-

```
$("[name='save']").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // alert("was");
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  //send the current form via ajax now
  form_name = "#"+id+"_form";
  data = $(form_name).serialize();
  alert(form_name);
  alert(data);

})
```

**Issue** is, I get **correct value** for `alert(form_name)` and correct data for `alert(data)` **when I click save for the first form**.

If I click save for the second form, I get correct data for `alert(form_name)` but I get **blank** for `data`. Why is jquery not picking up data?

Some help would be nice, I'm literally banging my head.

Edit :-

//this is the real line :-

```
<form action="" method="post" id="<?php echo $expereince_details->header_name; ?>_form">
```

Comment: close id attributes with quote 
<form method="post" action="" id="Television_form"> and <form method="post" action="" id="Video_form">

Comment: `id` of `form` missing  trailing `"(double quotes)` and jQuery need to change like this:- `$("button[name='save']").click(function(e){`

Comment: Oh no guys, that is the not the error. I wrote the form code directly and missed the quotes.

Updated it.

Answer (score 3):

Your form tags aren't closed properly, they are missing a `"` on the ID.

`<form method="post" action="" id="Video_form">`

Also you may want to consider attaching the event to the form rather than the buttons, it makes for easier development.

The below way no longer relies on IDs.

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = $(this).serialize();

    console.log(data);


    return false;
})
```

Comment: Oh no guys, that is the not the error. I wrote the form code directly and missed the quotes.

Updated it.

Comment: @xanderpower consider my answer above, by not relying on ID's, but rather the form element itself. This should solve your problem, though I realise it's not a direct solution.

Comment: @lan

Just tested it. It throws same data in console for all forms. And the data is the data of the first form. Here's an image :- https://gyazo.com/9e8f427afbc3ed2d9b941dde2ed17fdb

Comment: @xanderpower Looks like you haven't set it up correctly, what is being dumped there is all the forms combined, could be missing a closing form tag making the submit button submit it as if it were 1 form.

Answer (score 0):

Ian answer perfect but also you need to add type submit to the button

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="submit" id="Television" name="save"> Save</button>
```